# Discord Attachments Link

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, python-re

Well if you would like to get the attachments from a Discord message, you can do it by the following way:

```
attachements = message.attachments
```

But it cannot get attachments which are sent with a link.

Like the following links:

```
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/722437402685341766/801262293693890580/banner.gif
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/281595941746900992/710992416039108748/unknown.png(I got it from a spam report)
```

They already have a different starting url.

How to extract them from the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Message.attachments` returns a list of `Attachment` instances, you can loop through them and use the `url` attribute

```py
attachments = message.attachments
urls = []

for attch in attachments:
    urls.append(attch.url)
```

If you want a one-liner

```py
urls = [attch.url for attch in attachments]
```

Comment: Yes, but as I have posted those links in the question. What if they aren't attached to the message, they are just links which directs to a photo or something like that. How to get those links?

Comment: Make your own url regex, find a pattern in the urls. An example regex would be [this one](https://gist.github.com/gruber/8891611), but it detects all URLs, not only image URLs

Comment: If possible, may you show it in a new answer so that I can put a tick on it and set it as the correct answer tysm